# Jquery how to make continious functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a click function, in that function i am creating a new `<div>` and wrapping no.of other div's inside as children. Once the children are added, I need to calculate each child's width and apply to the parent (what I created), is it possible to do as chain function?

```
$('.thick-gallery-slide').wrapAll('<div id="tAllSlides" />')
```

There is no.of `.thick-gallery-slide` added to `#tAllSlides`, but how do I find the childrens and apply the total width to the parent `('#tAllSlides')` ?

Any help? I am looking on continuous functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try the find() method of jQuery.